# Time complexity - recursive call

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, code-complexity

I am trying to understand how to compute the time complexity of an algorithm .

I have this piece of code:
This is the whole method:

```
public void solve(int i) {
    if(i < 2) {
        return;
    }
    solve(i-1); //recursive call
    int x = v[n-i];
    for(int j = n-i+1; j < n; j++) {
        if(x > v[j]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I think the complexity is O(n). Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: What is `solve(i-1);`?!

Comment: This could be helpful: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Okay at least now we have the source of `solve`. What's `n`? What's `v`?

Comment: Thanks. n is a number read from a file and v is an array with n elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity should be `O(N^2)` as you will have `N + (N-1) + (N-2) + 1 = N ( N + 1 ) / 2` iterations in worst case.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check the article

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is `O(i^2)`, `n` here no matter.

The function will run `i` times (until `i<2`). each iteration will run `i` times (n-(n-i+1)=i-1).

We can call it `O(N^2)` when `N` mention to `i`.

**Note!** `N` and `n` are not the same here!